# How to copy a file from laravel storage into a directory out of project directory

Tags: php, linux, laravel

I have developed a Laravel project in which some images are uploaded to the `/storage/app/public` directory via a form. I want to copy each image into a directory in `/var/www/html` on my linux server. I tried two solutions but neither of them worked.

```
$cmd = "cp /var/www/html/project/storage/app/public/a3mvoXHR7iANhninQe4TiSavWLRxHQU7kD2so8de.jpeg 
/var/www/html/images/a3mvoXHR7iANhninQe4TiSavWLRxHQU7kD2so8de.jpeg";

exec($cmd);
```

The command works in linux, but returns `1` with no error in laravel.
I also tried the code below, but it can not copy a file into a directory outside the project.

```
Storage::copy("public/a3mvoXHR7iANhninQe4TiSavWLRxHQU7kD2so8de.jpeg ",
"/var/www/html/images/a3mvoXHR7iANhninQe4TiSavWLRxHQU7kD2so8de.jpeg ");
```

Comment: is directory have write permission?

Comment: I think, It's not normal to copy from inside to outside the project, But with full path it should work. You have to check permission levels.

Comment: First try to execute the command directly in your command line console and see what errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File::copy(storage_path() . '/app/public/a3mvoXHR7iANhninQe4TiSavWLRxHQU7kD2so8de.jpeg', '/var/www/html/images/a3mvoXHR7iANhninQe4TiSavWLRxHQU7kD2so8de.jpeg');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a symlink in your `storage/app` path to the directory that is required:

```
/var/www/html
```